# Splitting a large table for better performance in a PHP Symfony API with Doctrine 2.7 and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm

I work in a company that deals with real estate data. Our API is built with PHP Symfony and uses Doctrine 2.7, and our database is in PostgreSQL.

The issue I am facing is that the "Ad" table, which contains all the advertisements, is growing exponentially and now requires splitting by department to improve performance. What is the best solution for this? Should I partition the table in PostgreSQL? If so, how can I make a partitioned table and a single Doctrine entity work together?

I tested the division of the main entity "Ad" into 98 sub-entities named "Ad_XX" where "XX" is the number of the department, with an algo in SQL which allows me to pass dynamic table names and be able to query the data.
But this is outside the scope of doctrine for its maintainability; hence the question about partitioning the main table "Ad"

Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please share the results (in plain text, as an update to your original question) from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers) for your problematic queries? And the DDL (also plain text) for the tables and indexes involved? Personally I only start thinking about table partitions when we have at least a hundred million to half a billion records and that depends of the size (in GB) of the table.

Comment: You need to find the problem and fix it.  Not just make random refactorings in the dark and hope that one of them does something.  What query is slow, and what the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for it?

Comment: Ok thanks for your comments, i'll check this before going back here if necessary ️